# File Uploading using Node js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I am really stuck with this issue. I want to upload a file from this API to another API but this code does not seems working when I am sending the form data, it is going as raw content.

form.append('attachment[attachment]', req.files.meeting_attachment);

fetching the data by this way gives **source.on is not a function**

```
router.post('/attachments', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('meeting_attachment[attachment]', Buffer.from(req.files.meeting_attachment.data), { filename: req.files.meeting_attachment.name });

    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'accept': '*/*'
      }
    };

    const url = `https://webhook.site/a307cf34-at22-70b4-3a84-7ef36062d72c`;
    const response = await axios.post(url, form, options).then((res) => {
      console.log("result", res);
    });
   
    res.json({ status: true, data: response.data });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err", err);
    res.status(404).json({ status: false, error: 'File type is not supported' });
  }
});
```

I am getting 400 Bad Request with this raw content
[image]

Postman request to the actual receiver API looks like this on webhoook and it uploaded the file successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The raw content is SVG, what did you intend to send?

Comment: Just like my API, the receiver API is also expecting the file in formData.

Comment: please check the added image